Newly Created calendar via Google Calendar API now showing app in calendar.google.com
Using the Google Calendar API I created multiple calendars (successfully, I can even add events to them)
however they are not showing up as calendars in calendar.google.com even when trying to subscribe to them manually via their  id@group.calendar.google.com
new calendar_v3.Calendar({ auth: oAuth2Client }).calendars.insert({
      requestBody: {
        summary: calendar,
      },
    });

Is there a way to be able to view them from there? It would make it easier for sharing & debugging.

If you are looking for them in the bottom left of the google calendar web app.
You need to insert them into the calendar list before they will show up there.
see calendarlist.insert
